# Google Sheets multi nested IF with AND statements not working correctly

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula

I have a trading sheet, where I enter my trades. It shows entry/price target and stop loss. The idea is to show the following;-If the trade hit the profit target, it will show ‘Target Hit’. If the trade hits the Stop loss, it will show ‘Stop Loss Hit’. If neither profit nor stop loss have been hit, it will show ‘Active’. This is for both Long and short positions.
Long $10, Stop loss $9 and profit target $12 Short $10, Stop Loss $11 and Profit Target $9
When I enter a long position, works perfect, but when I enter a short, it does not for some reason. Can anyone check the code to see where I have gone wrong?
I have added a link to my spreadsheet so if someone can take a look and see where I have messed up.

[Google Sheet Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zidzue4lvDXvfjhLM52PFcdo40ZjQFK3zv-LOrG_fDE/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: After a good nights sleep and fresh eyes, I think I've got it working how I wanted. If anyone know how the code neater, please let me know.  I used this - =IF(ISBLANK(D18),"",IF(AND(D18="Long", C18>=H18),  "Target Hit", 
 IF(AND(D18="Long", C18<=J18), "Stop Loss", 
 IF(AND(D18="Short", C18<=H18), "Target Hit", 
 IF(AND(D18="Short", C18>=J18), "Stop Loss", "Active")))))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this array formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(D4:D), ,
 IF((D4:D="Long") *(C4:C>=H4:H), "Target Hit", 
 IF((D4:D="Long") *(C4:C<=J4:J), "Stop Loss", 
 IF((D4:D="Short")*(C4:C<=H4:H), "Target Hit", 
 IF((D4:D="Short")*(C4:C>=J4:J), "Stop Loss", "Active"))))))
```

[image: 0]

### [demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sm3gGvbK7YvvGalPYd8ZA1M0DSshcr5U_yGLF8YkmWQ/edit#gid=1659345449)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the formula I came up with when looking at your previous question (now deleted):

```
=IF(D21="Long",IF(C21>=H21,"Target Hit Long",IF(C21<=J21,"Stop Loss Long",IF(C21<H21,"Active Long"))),
IF(D21="Short",IF(C21<=H21,"Target Hit Short",IF(C21>=J21,"Stop Loss Short",IF(,C21>J21,"Active Short"))),""))
```

The thing is that you don't need to keep re-checking that the transaction is either short or long - the structure is basically:

```
If Long
    Do long stuff
else
    If short 
       Do short stuff
    else
       Do nothing
```